# sending e-mails automatically

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to setup a program which can automatically send e-mails. However, the first step doesn't even work for me and it gives this error:

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: 127.0.0.1, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2209)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at server.main(server.java:46)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:148)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:540)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:353)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:239)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2175)
    ... 7 more
```

This is the code:

```
// File Name SendEmail.java

import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class server {

   public static void main(String [] args) {    
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "my other email properly written";

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = "my email properly written";

      // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
      String host = "127.0.0.1";

      // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

      // Get the default Session object.
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try {
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("This is actual message");

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      } catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this happens and how to solve this? My e-mail is actually open etc. And because it's localhost I have no idea why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Did you install SMTP Server in your local host?

Comment: Are you running an email __server__ on localhost, or do you just have an email __client__ open?

Comment: @AJNeufeld i'm running the windows mail which is always installed on windows. Now my question is, is this considered "localhost" or a client?

Comment: also installed hMailServer though, trying the other way now

Comment: “Mail is an email and newsgroup **client** ...” [Mail (Windows) Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_(Windows)).  hMailServer sounds like it will be a real server, so if it is running on localhost, your code should work.  However, you don’t need to run a server on localhost; you just need to connect to, and send the mail through, an actual email server.  It doesn’t have to be on localhost.  Instead of struggling to setup and run your own server, and accidentally creating an open relay for spam, look into using your existing email service.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Now it does give the success message, it just doesn't actually send lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to a SMTP server would require the smtp host port and the security settings if applicable.

```
Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "hostname") #
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "portnumber") #25
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "boolean value true or false") 
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "boolean value true or false")
```

Usually a session need to be created (a Java mail session using the username and password and the properties), that is missing in the code above. For demonstration purpose,

```
 Session session = javax.mail.Session.getInstance( props, 
         new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
               return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication("username", "password"); //username and password
       }
         });
```

Comment: isnt the first code the same as System.getProperties?

Comment: try catch is required for the code block that throws a MessagingException . The code that sets the property, and create session wont. so above the try catch.

Comment: No its not the same code, the session can be created using a properties object and it can be a new property object altogether. Doesn't matter as long as the connection properties are set correctly for the mail session, might not be able to connect to smtp and send mail just with the hostname specified.

Comment: still doesnt work, could that be because of for example firewall

Comment: my server does say it has processed those messages, but in the actual client i dont see the message and neither in the one that should receive the mail

Comment: Try message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("xxxy@xzv.nnnn")); , will  ensure the to address is proper email address.

Comment: no its working,  my mailbox blocked port 25, because of infections or smth. They had their own port tho. !! Working fine now, thanks!